# Kotlin readLine gives error in a basic program where input is taken from user and the same is shown as output

Tags: kotlin, readline

The following code :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
print("Write anything here: ")

val enteredString = readLine()
println("You have entered this: $enteredString")
```

}

gives the following error in KotlinPlayground :

```
Write anything here: You have entered this: null
```

*Here, the user doesn't get an opportunity to enter input. After the initial print statement gets executed, **the compiler is not waiting for the user to give input** and skips to the next print statement. **Why is it happening?** I have tried the same in several other online Kotlin compilers but I am getting the same error.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no error. `readLine` just returns `null` (because Kotlin Playground doesn't have a console to read from), and it's printed as expected.

E.g. on https://ideone.com/ you can say what to use for input and it'll print that line (though its Kotlin version is pretty old).

Comment: The problem is that the user is not getting an opportunity to give input. What can i do to ensure the user gets a chance to give input.

Comment: If you compile and run this program on your computer, you'll get the input. Kotlin Playground just doesn't support it. As mentioned, ideone is an online compiler which does, but even there you need to enter it in advance.

Comment: Thanks! It helped.

Comment: Then you may want to accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Because Kotlin playground have no user input console and this is not an error. For user input you can either use https://ideone.com/  or 
https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-kotlin-online/

I will recommend you to use the second on which is `jdoodle`. It is pretty much faster to run and read user input and almost use the latest version of Kotlin and JRE.

And if you like to play (run) with command line argument then it will good for you with `jdoodle`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Kotlin Playground by using `JS` as the destination platform - click on the `JVM` dropdown (top left, to the right of the kotlin version) and change to `JS`.

Now you can call JavaScript - **only using constant strings**, e.g.

```
fun main() {
    val name = js("prompt('Please enter your name', 'Bob')")
    println("Hello $name")
}
```

For another example, using a common function, see https://pl.kotl.in/MkhfYNS47

Note: if you try this:

```
fun promptName(default: String = "") {
    return js("prompt('Please enter your name', '$default')")
}
```

You will get a compilation error - `Argument must be string constant`.

*Note that `JS IR` as an option ran much slower and had an issue with default type needing to be stated for the linked code*

Comment: Note: Adding a loop to prompt then print causes issues - the print/println output is not updated while the prompt is shown.  See https://pl.kotl.in/I05VqRZTs for an example.